# How to force syntax highlighting for large XML files?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

For large XML files it seems like the Visual Studio text editor will not attempt to do syntax highlighting, so everything is black and white.

Is there a way to force it to parse for highlighting?

Comment: Just how large are we talking about here?

Comment: @Karan I'm sorry, it's 14MB.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed the Output window shows a warning: `'file.xml' is too large to open with XML editor. The maximum file size is '10' MB. Please update the registry key 'HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config\XmlEditor\MaxFileSizeSupportedByLanguageService' to change the maximum size.` Changed that fixed it =!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run this in powershell for VS 2017 and higher

```
$vsWherePath = Join-Path ${env:ProgramFiles(x86)} "Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe"
$installPath = & $vsWherePath -all -products * -latest -property installationPath
$VsRegEdit = Join-Path $installPath 'Common7\IDE\vsregedit.exe'
& $VsRegEdit read "$installPath" "HKLM" "XmlEditor" "MaxFileSizeSupportedByLanguageService" string
& $VsRegEdit set "$installPath" "HKLM" "XmlEditor" "MaxFileSizeSupportedByLanguageService" string 100
& $VsRegEdit read "$installPath" "HKLM" "XmlEditor" "MaxFileSizeSupportedByLanguageService" string
```

Comment: With just SSDT installed I had to add "-products *" to the $vsWherePath args in order for the install path to be correctly picked up

Comment: I needed to update VS2019 to use a VS2019-specific extension but had VS2022 installed. I had to change script `$installPath = &$vsWherePath -version [16.0,17.0] -property installationPath` to update the appropriate key. And probably worth mentioning, updating the HKCU key as suggested in the error message had no affect.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out the maximum file size for the XML editor is 10 MB. After changing the limit in the following key, syntax highlighting is back with no noticeable performance issues:

`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config\XmlEditor\MaxFileSizeSupported‌​ByLanguageService`

Run `regedit` to navigate to that path in the Windows Registry. `HKCU` stands for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`.